# Basic filter/search list of Div/a elements

Tags: javascript, html, list, filter

I'm really new to javascript.

I'm looking for a "basic filter/search list" like the link below, but with elements "DIV" and "A" instead of "UL" and "LI".

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list)

Can you help me trying to figure it out ? :(
I think I'm not really far of the expected result but I fail. Please don't be rude, i try to understand how it works.
Here below my actual code :

```html
<div id="myDIV">
    <a href="#">Banana</a>
        <a href="#">Apple</a>
        <a href="#">Tomato</a>
        <a href="#">Peach</a>
  </div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, a, aInDiv, i, txtValue;

    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    aInDiv = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; i < aInDiv.length; i++) {
        a = aInDiv[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            aInDiv[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            aInDiv[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: With all due respect, what is your question?

Comment: You're not executing your function and there are some bugs in your example. I fixed it below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. always remember that declaring a function is not the same as running it. If you have code inside of a function body, you must call that function to execute the code.
2. There was no input in your example, resulting in all `a` elements being given the `display: none` property, filtering them all out.

```html
<div id="myDIV">
    <a href="#">Banana</a>
        <a href="#">Apple</a>
        <a href="#">Tomato</a>
        <a href="#">Peach</a>
  </div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, a, aInDiv, i, txtValue;

    div = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    aInDiv = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; i < aInDiv.length; i++) {
        a = aInDiv[i];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;

        aInDiv[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
myFunction()
</script>
```